# Strange joomla mobile site behavior

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, malware

Till 2 days ago, everything was great with my Joomla site (web shop), but now I have strange problem. Don't know if it is hack, malware, or something else, but here is what is so strange:

When I am looking and browsing on desktop site (on my laptop or desktop computer), everything is OK and no problem, also, when I am looking trough site with my mobile phone or small tablet everything is still OK, but when I press "back button" in browser, it doesn't take me back on my mobile web site, but starts jumping trough several web addresses and then ends on some address that is some kind advertise or "download this" - "download that" stuff.

Everything is OK on mobile when I am going in forward trough menu, trough shop item and putting it to cart, but every time I press back, it doesn't matter where I am on web site, or from which device is browsing (iOS or Android), first time I press "back" it goes to some advertise site.

There is no problem on my mobile device if I put site to "browse as desktop version". When is desktop verison, also on my mobile device I can go back and advance trough site, but as soon as I put it to "mobile version" (responsive), back button is just "hacked".

Is it possible that this is somewhere in my code? Because I have replace all theme files again trough FTP, also, I have made site restore from several days ago and still same problem.
I did not touch my server, because everything is OK with desktop version, so I assume that this is problem somewhere in code for mobile version.

Did any of you stump on similar problem? I have searching trough web for similar problem last 2 days but nothing even close to this one :/

I'll appreciate for any kind of help, this site is really very important to me and I have insert month and month of hard work in it... :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to reduce the size of your browser when on your desktop ? Or something like Responsive Design Mode of the Developer menu of FireFox ? Can you post the URL ?

Comment: I upgrade Virtuemart and Joomla to latest version, also, my hosting provider upgrade PHP version for me to 7.1, and now seems to be OK, but I still have some problems.

I still need to press 5x-6x times "back" to really go one page back.

You can try it here: www.box2.appleoprema.com

Thanks

Comment: does the hashtag sign has something to do with it? I see that when I enter on my mobile site, in my url address at the end there is hashtag sign, like this:

www.box2.appleoprema.com/#

Comment: Did you try to disable Joomla cache ?

Comment: It wasn't on at all. It is off, I cleared all caches, nothing happened. All versions of Joomla and vitruemart are up to date. I have scanned for malware on docents web sites and components inside joomla, everything is clean. But problem remains... :/

Comment: I looked at it yesterday. I saw a redirection to  get.imobilecontent.tk. when trying to go back. This redirects to another page. The one you don't like. I thought about cache because it was always redirecting to the same page. Just trying to help...

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate. I am trying to get rid of that "back button" thing, and after 3 days, I just let it go. I was working on this page for several month, and day before putting it online that happened. I am just tired of looking for solutions. Today I started on new page in Wordpress and to come with same thing in WP will need again several month. Hope it will be online for Christmas holidays.... :( :'(

Comment: May be you can post in Joomla Meta ? Don't know is it is equivalent to post here with the caorrect tags...

Comment: Just manage to resolve the problem. I did so many thing from tens, maybe even twenty FTP reloads of site and installing again to cPanel changing and  I_don't_know_what_else things. Even contact my domain provider, they have backup my site several times, several different date copies... Really, 5 days no sleep and a lot of sitting in front of a screen. It seems that it was jQuery or Java problem, not sure what, because I have play with setting of my theme in admin panel and suddenly starting to work. I think it was something with Java, possible that malware was there.

Comment: Happy it worked for you. You're site is really cool.